# Wordpress - archive page: list posts by year

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I need to get something like this:

## 2014

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3
- post 4

## 2013

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how Wordpress stores the post date, but when querying you need to do something like this.  `SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
$yearly = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1));
$prev_year = null;
if( $yearly->have_posts() ) : while( $yearly->have_posts() ) : $yearly->the_post();
      $this_year = get_the_date('Y');
      if ($prev_year != $this_year) {
          if (!is_null($prev_year)) {
             echo '</ul>';
          }
          echo '<h3>' . $this_year . '</h3>';
          echo '<ul>';
      }
      echo '<li>';
      echo '</li>';
      $prev_year = $this_year;
    endwhile;    
    echo '</ul>';
endif;
```

Please take a look at the documentation as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query